# Enormous Input - for loop faster than list comprehension

Tags: python, list-comprehension

I'm trying to solve a codechef beginner problem - [Enormous Input Test](http://www.codechef.com/problems/INTEST). My code

```
a,b = [ int(i) for i in raw_input().split()]
print [input()%b==0 for i in range(a)].count(True)
```

gets timed out. Another [solution](http://www.codechef.com/viewsolution/989892), which uses basic for-loops, seems to be working fine.

I believe that list comprehension is quicker than basic for - loops. Then why is the former slower? Also will using generators in this case reduce the memory used and perform the computation faster, if so how can I do it?

Comment: Forcing a list on purpose? That *will* be materialized first... (and possibly consuming huge amounts of memory in the process for an "enormous input test")

Comment: sorry @pst I didnt understand. "Forcing a list" meaning?

Comment: The square brackets create a list, the entirety of which is stored in memory.  You probably want to use parentheses instead to get a generator comprehension: `(int(i) for i in raw_input().split())`  This uses "lazy evaluation", only doing the calculations when you try to get them, and only storing as many as needed for whatever you're doing with them.  After you're done with each value, it deletes it from memory.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Why do you believe that list comprehension is quicker than basic `for` loops?  (Hint: they are both implemented using the same underlying instructions.)

Your code will be executed in some manner like this:

```
a, b = ...
temp = []
for i in range(a):
    temp.append(int(raw_input()) % b == 0)
print temp.count(True)
```

As you can see, it creates a large list in memory, iterates over it to create a second list, and then iterates over the second list to create a count.  The list does not ever need to be created.

```
a, b = ...
count = 0
for i in xrange(a):
    if int(raw_input()) % b == 0:
        count += 1
print count
```

Some compilers are capable of optimizing hylomorphisms to remove the intermideate list, but I know of no Python implementation capable of this.  So you are stuck optimizing by hand.

**Note:** Do not use `input` in Python 2.x, unless you know what you are doing.  I have changed the code to use `int(raw_input())` because that is safe, whereas `input()` is dangerous.

Comment: Thank you for clarifying the basics. What do mean input() is dangerous?

Comment: @Mellkor: It evaluates user input as Python code.  It is about as dangerous as you can get without attaching dynamite to the computer.

Comment: hmm. doesn't input() return the type of the object provided so wouldn't it be better than using raw_input() and typecasting it? I've not programmed enough in Python to understand your statement to its extent.

Comment: There is no such thing as typecasting in Python, since Python is a dynamic language.  `input()` *evaluates* user input, which means it allows an attacker to run *any code.*  All `int()` does is parse a string as an integer.  You want to parse a string as an integer, so you use `int()`.  You don't want to let attackers run arbitrary code in your program, so you don't want to use `input()`.  The `input()` function happens to do the right thing if the user types in an integer, but it can do *very bad things* if the user types in something else.  Whereas `int()` fails quite nicely on bad input.

Comment: Put another way, `input()` is basically the same as `eval(raw_input())`.  You really want `int(raw_input())` instead, not `eval(raw_input())`.  The `eval()` function is dangerous, just like `input()`.